# Trying to make a sound play in my html document. by pressing a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, interactive

I am trying to make a "interactive business card" as my design course calls it, and i want to make a piano with playable buttons. The problem is that no matter what i try, the sound won't play in any browser. I startet out with linking the sound to one of the buttons in javascript/jQuery (i am pretty new to both languages, so i can not exactly say that i know what i am doing.) but now i just want to hear the sound, so i incorporated it into my html document.

Here is the code:

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/>
<h1>"Yo Dawg, i heard you like muzic."</h1>
<p>"hej"</p>


    </head>
<body>
    <div id= "wholething">
    <div id= "whitekey1">
        <div id= "blackkey2"></div></div>


    <div id= "whitekey2">
        </div>

    <div id= "whitekey1">
        <div id="blackkey3"></div>
        </div>

    <div id= "whitekey3">
        <div id = "blackkey2"></div>
        </div>

        <div id= "whitekey4">
        <div id = "blackkey2"></div>
        </div>
        <div id= "whitekey1">
        <div id = "blackkey2"></div>
        </div>

        <div id= "whitekey3"></div>

        <div id= "whitekey2">
        <div id = "blackkey1"></div>
        </div>
        <div id= "whitekey4">
        <div id = "blackkey1"></div>
        </div>
        <div id= "whitekey1">
        <div id = "blackkey2"></div>
        </div>
    </div> 
<script type= "text/javascript" src= "jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
<script type= "text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

<span id="dummy"></span>
<p><a href="#" onclick="playSound('afrique-kissingmylove.wav');">Click here to             hear a bird sing</a></p>

    <p onmouseover="playSound('afrique-kissingmylove.wav');">Or you can put your mouse over this paragraph to hear the same bird sound.</p>



</body>
```

What am i doing wrong? how do i make the sound play when you press the black and white keys? (preferably using javascript/jQuery.)

Comment: And where's the `playSound` function ?

Comment: Where are your event handlers for the black/white keys click?

Comment: Check this http://kahimyang.info/kauswagan/code-blogs/1652/how-to-play-a-sound-when-an-element-is-clicked-in-html-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to implement the `playSound` function using javascript. 
You could do something like this :

```
function playSound(file)
{
  var aud=new Audio(file);
  aud.play();
}
```

And also do this in your html, :

```
<p onclick="playSound('afrique-kissingmylove.mp3');">Click here to             hear a bird sing</p>
```

The anchor tag is unnecessary. And assuming that you want to make a piano(sorry your question is very unclear),you can do this for all your divs :

```
<div id= "whitekey1" onclick="playSound('whitekey1.mp3');">
    <div id = "blackkey2" onclick="playSound('blackkey2.mp3');"></div>
</div>
```

You can download the Piano name files from here and re-name them accordingly : https://www.freesound.org/people/pinkyfinger/packs/4409/

*Please tick that green label on the left,if it worked. Happy Coding!*

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems pretty straight forward, but my sound is still not playing. Where am i supposed to store the song file? And yes, i am trying to make a piano :)

Comment: You can store the sound in the same directory which contains you html file. Like you do for images. Or if you've kept it in a folder called "foo", then this what you would do 
`var aud=new Audio('foo/'+file);`.

And i forgot to mention that this method works for **MP3 Files only**.Heres the link to the files: https://www.freesound.org/people/pinkyfinger/packs/4409/

Please upvote also. :) Happy Coding!

Comment: Thanks again! I'm trying to i will upvote as soon as i have enough points :)